# Getting a Type Error "Cannot read property '0' of undefined at HTMLButtonElement.generateQuiz

Tags: javascript, html, dom, undefined, typeerror

1.This is where Im getting my only error, says "Cannot read property '0' of undefined at HTMLButtonElement.generateQuiz.

```
setTime();
        var qSelect = new Question(quizQuestions[quesNum].answers, quizQuestions[quesNum].question, quizQuestions[quesNum].right);
        quesNum += 1;
        qSelect.questionOut();
    }
```

```
function resultsModalShow(x) {
    var tagNew;
    document.querySelector("#testresults").innerHTML = '';
    document.querySelector(".modal-title").innerHTML = "Test results for: " + results[x].name + ". Time left :" + results[x].time + " seconds";
    for (var i = 0; i < quizQuestions.length; i++) {
        tagNew = document.createElement("H3");
        tagNew.textContent = (i + 1) + ". Question  " + quizQuestions[i].question;
        document.querySelector("#testresults").appendChild(tagNew);
        tagNew = document.createElement("H4");
        tagNew.textContent = "Correct answer: " + quizQuestions[i].right;
        document.querySelector("#testresults").appendChild(tagNew);
        tagNew = document.createElement("H4");
        tagNew.textContent = results[x].name + "'s answer: " + results[x].quiz[i];
        if (quizQuestions[i].right != results[x].quiz[i]) {
            tagNew.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
        }
        document.querySelector("#testresults").appendChild(tagNew);
    }
```

Comment: Hmmm. we'll need more code to help you i think.  All i see here is a function.  In your function you defined a variable, added 1 to an undefined variable then called a phantom function.  Then you stated there's an error to a phantom element (button).

Comment: sounds like `quizQuestions` is undefined

Comment: how do i define quiz questions? sorry im lost rn

Comment: figured it out, had my initial declare of quizQuestions set to zero THANK you all